# How do I copy the different columns from text file into variables

Tags: java, arrays, startswith

The text file i have made looks as follows:
(each item represents a column): Unique Identifier  Title   Year    Rating  Metascore   Votes   Description Runtime (Minutes)   Revenue (Millions)  Actors  Director    Genre (all) Genre 1 Genre 2     Genre 3

There are about 250 movies in the list. I am trying to get java to search for the movietitle variable from the list and then return that whole line.

code returns the catch.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class showingthemovies {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String movieid;
    String movietitle;
    String yearstring;
    int year;
    String genres;
    String imdbratingstring;
    double imdbrating;
    String directors;
    String actors;
    String plot;

    movietitle = "Antitrust";

    int lineNumber = 0; 

            try{
                BufferedReader myFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("src/workinglist5.txt")); // The file is read. 
                String sCurrentLine;
                String [] moviedata = new String [20];

            while ((sCurrentLine = myFile.readLine()) != null){
                    if (sCurrentLine.startsWith(movietitle)) {

                        moviedata = sCurrentLine.split("\t");   


                        yearstring = moviedata [1];
                            year =  Integer.parseInt(yearstring);
                        genres = moviedata [10];
                        imdbratingstring = moviedata [2];
                            imdbrating =  Double.parseDouble(imdbratingstring);
                        directors = moviedata [9];
                        actors = moviedata [10];
                        plot = moviedata [5];

                System.out.println("Movie Title:" + movietitle);
                System.out.println("Released in:" + year);
                System.out.println("Genre(s):" + genres);
                System.out.println("IMDB Rating:" + imdbrating);
                System.out.println("Directed by:" + directors);
                System.out.println("Starring:" + actors);
                System.out.println("Plot Summary:" + plot);
                lineNumber++;
                 break;

                    } 
                    myFile.close(); // The file is closed. 

                    }} catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("I/O exception error when reading file"); // Error message. 

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: You really should make a `Movie` class and make all those variables into fields of the class, then it would be easy to make a `List<Movie>` out of the 250 `Movies` and do whatever you want with the data easily (if there was a lot more `Movies` I wouldn't store the whole file in memory).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, could you maybe link me a tutorial page/vid that could get me started?

Comment: Try this [one](https://www.udemy.com/course/practice-java-by-building-projects/), it has a good intro into using Objected Oriented ideas, instead of doing everything procedural like you are doing.

Comment: @halfabridge You said _code returns the catch._ Do you mean, the program is throwing an exception and going to the catch block? If so, would you print the stack trace and post it here?